# Is there a way to merge multiple mono error signals?

Tags: java, mono, spring-webflux, project-reactor, flux

Is there a way to merge multiple error signals? For example:

```
    return Mono.zipDelayError(
        monoOne(), //throws ValidationException with list of validation details 1
        monoTwo(),
        monoThree() //throws ValidationException with list of validation details 2
    )
    .then();
}
```

as a result I want to return ValidationException with merged list of validation details

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `Exceptions.unwrapMultiple()` utility method to obtain a `List<Throwable>`, allowing you to then reduce that list to a single `ValidationException` (or do any other checking / processing you like.)

Then it's just a case of wrapping the above in `onErrorMap()`:

```
Mono.zipDelayError(
        Mono.error(new ValidationException("Reason 1")),
        Mono.just("ok"),
        Mono.error(new ValidationException("Reason 2"))
)
.onErrorMap(e ->
        Exceptions.unwrapMultiple(e).stream()
                .reduce((e1, e2) -> new ValidationException(String.join(", ", e1.getMessage(), e2.getMessage()))).get()
);
```

...which gives:

```
Exception in thread "main" reactor.core.Exceptions$ReactiveException: ValidationException: Reason 1, Reason 2
```

Note that `Exceptions.unwrapMultiple()` will still work for the case where the exception *isn't* a multiple - in that case you'll just get a singleton list.